# How can I look up functions in the module I wrote in Pycharm

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm, ide

When I was learning Python, I used Jupyter notebook. But recently, I started to use Pycharm.
When I import module I wrote in Jupyter notebook, I can get a list of functions in it by pressing TAB.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeHib.png)

But in Pycharm, It seems like I am not able to look up functions from the Module I wrote.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NiGt.png)
You can see there is not function called checkIfNumeric or findMax.
How can I look up functions in Pycharm from modules which is not from standard library?

Comment: Andy, it looks like your import statement might be off (the red underlining indicates a problem). Usually it's something like import funcFromList from function_library as Func   (replace function_library with whatever module that function resides in). Moreover, is funcFromList a function or a module. If it's a function, you shouldn't expect to have other functions to choose from.

Comment: Thanks Ben. The import statement did not work properly. The module I wrote should be in working directory, now I am able to get the same reference list in Pycharm.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Andy. Best of luck!